# Write JSON file from MySql using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to add ***Data*** before the array and it is written into the converted json.
I have checked that there are no errors when converting, but why isn't there?

This the code

```
$response = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $response[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
    //write to json file
$fp = fopen('op.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode('{"Data":', $response), '}');// JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
fclose($fp);
```

Previous results like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "kiko",
    "score": "999"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "johyn",
    "score": "88"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "aaaani",
    "score": "99"
  }
]
```

I want the results like this

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "kiko",
      "score": "999"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "johyn",
      "score": "88"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "aaaani",
      "score": "99"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `fwrite($fp, '{"Data":' . json_encode($response). '}');`

Comment: You can also replace the loop and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`  with [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to code the JSON and then `json_encode()` it you can use an array to generate the desired output:

```
$response = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $response[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
    //write to json file
$fp = fopen('op.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode(array('Data' => $response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); // JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
fclose($fp);
```

In addition, `json_encode()` has the ability to *pretty print* the json by supplying the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode()` encodes an array or object to a JSON String, so make the parameter an array and it will work

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode(["Data" => $response]);
```

Or to get JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode(["Data" => $response], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```